# How to pass empty string into integer in python?

Tags: python

i have one file which is highcore.txt and it is empty.

i want if txt file is empty or if any number which is score is greater than any number in txt file , update the txt file , here is my code

```
def game():
   return 115

score = game()
with open("highscore.txt") as f:
   highScoreStr = f.read()
if int(highScoreStr)<score or highScoreStr=='':
   with open("highscore.txt","w") as f:
       f.write(str(score))
```

it is giving error

```
    if int(highScoreStr)<score or highScoreStr=='':
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

how to fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to pass an empty string through `int()`

Since you know it starts as an empty string you're probably better off writing 2 `if` statements:

```
if highScorStr == '':
    with open("highscore.txt","w") as f:
       f.write(str(score))
if int(highScoreStr)<score:
    with open("highscore.txt","w") as f:
       f.write(str(score))
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if int(highScoreStr)<score or highScoreStr=='':
```

using

```
if highScoreStr=='' or int(highScoreStr)<score:
```

`or` does short-circuit if first part is True, that is second is not checked.